# Type selection for literal numeric values in C

Tags: c

I'm wondering about this: when I try to assign an integer value to an `int` variable (16-bit compiler, 2 bytes for integers) let's say:

```
int a;

a=40000;
```

that can't be represented with the range of the type it will be truncated. But what I'm seeing is that the resulting value in **a** is the bit pattern for -25000 (or some close number) which means that the binary representation that the compiler chooses for decimal 40000 was unsigned integer representation. And that raises my question: how does the compiler choose the type for this literal expression?

I'm guessing it uses the type capable of handling the value with less storage space needed.

Comment: A good compiler would emit a warning in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behaviour here differs between C89 and C99.

In C89, a decimal integer literal takes the first of these types in which it can be represented:

```
int, long, unsigned long
```

In C99, a decimal integer literal takes the first of these types in which it can be represented:

```
int, long, long long
```

For your particular code snippet it makes no difference, since 40000 is guaranteed to fit in a long, but there are a few significant differences between C89 and C99 literals.

Some of those consequences are described here:

http://www.hardtoc.com/archives/119

Answer (score 2):

From [Kernighan & Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)), Appendix A2.5.1 (Integer Constants), p 193:

> The type of an integer constant
>   depends on its form, value and
>   suffix...If it is unsuffixed and
>   decimal, it has the first of these
>   types in which its value can be
>   represented: int, long int, unsigned
>   long int.

Note that this answer is only relevant to C89, as the 2nd Edition of the "C Programming Language" predates the C99 standard.

Answer (score 1):

40000 in hexadecimal is 0x9C40.  Notice that the most significant bit of this value is a 1 (0x8000).  Assuming a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, that means that if you cram 0x9C40 into a signed representation, then, by subtracting the value at the sign bit from the rest, you will get 0x1C40 - 0x8000 = -0x63C0 = -25536 (base 10).

Have a look at [INT00-C. Understand the data model used by your implementation(s)](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT00-C.+Understand+the+data+model+used+by+your+implementation(s)) and [INT02-C. Understand integer conversion rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) on the CERT C Secure Coding Standard Wiki for more information.

Comment: True and relevant, but I think the actual question is "how does the compiler choose the type for the literal", not "what happens when I assign to int from that type".