# Why do we put suffixes following numeric literals?

Tags: c

I am pretty much sure this question has been answered, though I didn't manage to find it. I know the rules for the type conversions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277799/type-selection-for-literal-numeric-values-in-c). Even if we assign `1` (which is by default of a type `signed int`) to `unsigned int` variable, the variable of type `unsigned int` will have the value if `1` in either case. In other words, why would I want to put `U` suffix, unless to avoid type conversion (if I intend to assign that value mostly to `unsigned int`s)?

Comment: What will be the result of `0xFFFFFFFF >> 1` on a 32-bit int compiler? What will be `0xFFFFFFFFU >> 1`

Comment: @EugeneSh.  `0xFFFFFFFF` is an `unsigned` on a 32-bit int/unsigned compiler.  `0xFFFFFFFFU` is also an unsigned value.  What difference do you see?

Comment: Is it due to the error prone, when typing in HEX format?

Comment: @chux You are right. Lets make it `-1 >> 1` versus `-1U >> 1` . https://ideone.com/LzkKnK

Comment: `0x7FFFFFFF << 1` shifts a signed type, likely into the sign position --> issues. `0x7FFFFFFFu << 1` --> no problem.

Comment: I think the genesis of the `u` suffix is more subtle. May be it has something to do with the processor's work optimization. For example: let suppose `int` is 8 bit long. Then this `unsigned int i = 255` would result in promoting `255` to an signed integer that can represent the number `255`, BUT the processor is not that good in calculus with numbers bigger than 8-bit (which is 255 - int16_t may be). Therefore if we put `u` behind the number like this: `255U` integer promotion would happen and processor is very happy when working with 8-bit numbers.

Comment: The upper comment is just a consideration that I do not persist to be true, but I hope it will help to understand my question.

Comment: @Hari If `int` is 8-bit,  255 is _not_ an `int`.  It would be a wider type, like `long`.  then `unsigned int i = 255` is assigning a `long` to `unsigned`.  Assignment of out of range values to an `unsigned` is well-defined.  If code was `unsigned int i = 255u`, that would be assigning an `unsigned` to `unsigned`.  No promotion occurs.  In this example, the net result is not different.  But if code was `#define A -1u  unsigned b = A << 1;` the results can differ.

Answer (score 3):

Literal value suffixes are most important when you need to precisely control the type.  For example 4 billion fits in an unsigned 32-bit int but not a signed one.  So if you do this, your compiler may complain:

```
printf("%u", 4000000000);
```

> warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'long'

Also one may use the float suffix `f` to ensure a value is used that way in arithmetic, such as `1f / x` (which could also be written `1. / x` or `1.0 / x`).  This is important if `x` might be an integral type but the result is meant to be floating point.

Comment: Literals don't need suffixes "to fit". The type of the literal is always suitable to hold that value, if such a type exists.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's true; I reworded part of my answer and gave a concrete example where it matters.

Comment: It's still not about the value being "out of range in the desired type".  If that's the case, then you're just out of luck.  On the contrary, it's about designating a different signedness or minimum integer rank (or both) than would be selected by default.

Comment: @KerrekSB Mostly, but not fully agree with [Literals don't need suffixes "to fit"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242582/why-do-we-put-suffixes-following-numeric-literals/40243626?noredirect=1#comment67747752_40242705)  That applies for `l` and `ll`, but not `u`.  Consider [integer constant greater than `LLONG_MAX`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40265895/2410359)

Comment: @chux: Or spell it in hex :-)

Answer (score 1):

An *integer constant* does not need a suffix to exist with a given value (aside from values representable as some unsigned in decimal but not signed).  The trick is what type is that constant and how is that used.

Suppress warning as the *integer decimal constant* cannot be presented as a `signed long long`.

```
                         // pow(2,64) - 1
unsigned long long x1 =  18446744073709551615; // warning
unsigned long long x2 =  18446744073709551615u;// no warning
```

Consider [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242582/why-do-we-put-suffixes-following-numeric-literals#comment67747741_40242582) example

```
-1 >> 1     // Rigth shifting negative values is implementation defined behavior
// versus
-1U >> 1    // Well defined.  -1U has the positive value of `UINT_MAX`
```

Sometime simple constants like `1u` are used for gently type conversion

```
// The product is the wider of the type of `x` or `unsigned`
x*1u
```

[@John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242705/2410359) provides a good `printf()` example.

---

The suffixes `u` and `U` insure the type is some unsigned integer like `unsigned` or wider.

The is no suffix to insure the type is signed.   Use *decimal* constants.

The suffixes `l` and `L` insure the type is at least `long/unsigned long` without changing it sign-ness.

The suffixes `ll` and `LL` insure the type is at least `long long/unsigned long long` without changing it sign-ness.

The is no suffix to insure the type is narrower than `int/unsigned`.

There is no standard suffix to insure the type is `intmax_t/uintmax_t`.

Comment: Beside the warnings (whose motivation I don't understand), I can't find reasonable explanation for using suffixes of type 'U' or 'u'. Being signed or unsigned integer literal does not affect the bit representation of the result. Once it is assigned to a variable, integer promotion be performed if the variable is qualified as unsigned and has rank greater than or equal.

Comment: I very much appreciate your efforts, although (may be because I can't put the question right) I don't understand how would it help me to put this `u/U` at the end of the integer literal. Why on the earth, would someone write something like this: `-1U' ? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Hairi  "Being signed or unsigned integer literal does not affect the bit representation of the result."  This is not clear and certainly not supported by the C standard.  Provide examples of what you mean.

Comment: @Hairi "Why ...write something like this: `-1U' ? It doesn't make sense to me." vs what?  Clearly state a given usage for a clear answer.