# unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1; print 0 with %llu, but unsigned long long resA = 4294967295 + 1; print 4294967296 with %llu

Tags: c, integer, printf, literals, integer-overflow

It seems that I found a bug when print value of `(0xffffffff + 1)` with `%llu` is `0`, see below code:

```
unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;  // number of f is 8
printf("resTestBad is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %ld\n", resTestBad, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

will output:

```
resTestBad is 0, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

I think that output is wrong, it should be output or say correct output:

```
resTestBad is 4294967296, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

And

```
unsigned long long resA = 4294967295 + 1; 
printf("resA is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resA, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

will output:

```
resA is 4294967296, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

But below code is no problem:

```
unsigned long long resTestAgain = 0xfffffffff + 1;   // number of f is 9
printf("resTestAgain is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestAgain, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

It will output(I think it right):

```
resTestAgain is 68719476736, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

My .c file is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s = 0xfffe;
    printf("s is %d\n", s);

    unsigned int ww = 0xfffe;
    printf("ww is %d\n", ww);

    unsigned long long resTestOk = 0xfffffffe + 1; 
    printf("resTestOk is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestOk, sizeof(unsigned long long));

    unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;  
    printf("resTestBad is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestBad, sizeof(unsigned long long));

    unsigned long long resTestAgain = 0xfffffffff + 1; 
    printf("resTestAgain is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestAgain, sizeof(unsigned long long));

    unsigned long long resA = 4294967295 + 1; 
    printf("resA is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resA, sizeof(unsigned long long));

    unsigned long long resTestUUU = 0xffffffffffffff + 1; 
    printf("resTestUUU is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestUUU, sizeof(unsigned long long));

    unsigned long long resH = (0xffffffff+1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
    printf("%llu\n", resH);

    unsigned long long resD = (4294967296) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
    printf("%llu\n", resD);

    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
s is 65534
ww is 65534
resTestOk is 4294967295, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
resTestBad is 0, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
resTestAgain is 68719476736, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
resA is 4294967296, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
resTestUUU is 72057594037927936, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
0
4
```

May be you don't believe that, I also don't believe, so I record a video that for prove I said.

See https://imgur.com/a/RAQVPxS

Is it a Bug of CPU or bug of VMWare Workstation? How can I solve it?

## Update

Sorry, may be my question is not clear, or say confusion for people.

Problem origin from that I want to test how many memory a 32-bit computer can access(I know it is 4GB, address from 0x00000000 to 0xffffffff, total number is 0xffffffff + 1, unit is bytes, so `(0xffffffff + 1)` / 1024 /1024 / 1024 = 4GB), so I use below code:

```
unsigned long long resH = (0xffffffff + 1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
printf("%llu\n", resH);
```

But it output number `0`, that is not what I want to get. I except output is 4. So I also use below code:

```
unsigned long long resQ = (4294967295 + 1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
printf("%llu\n", resQ);
```

It output 4 that what is I except. So I want to find out what reason result to different of result.

Then I use below code:

```
unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1; 
printf("resTestBad is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestBad, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

it output:

```
resTestBad is 0, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

That not is my except, so I test below code:

```
unsigned long long resTestAgain = 0xfffffffff + 1; 
printf("resTestAgain is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resTestAgain, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

it output:

```
resTestAgain is 68719476736, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

as below code:

```
unsigned long long resA = 4294967295 + 1; 
printf("resA is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %zu\n", resA, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

it output:

```
resA is 4294967296, sizeof(unsigned long long) is 8
```

By see answer, now I understand why 0xffffffff + 1 output 0.

**But now I can't understand that value size of 0xffffffff and 4294967295 is the same, why 0xffffffff as `unsigned int` type(occupy 32-bit), however 4294967295 may be as `long` or `long long` or other type(occupy 64-bit)**.

Comment: `0xffffffffULL + 1ULL`

Comment: @Ry- Must have a UL? Is it ok if no UL?

Comment: Sidenote: The correct format specifier for `size_t` which is result type of `sizeof` is `%zu`

Comment: As you demonstrate in your code, the result is different. Is that OK for you or not?

Comment: @Gerhardh But I use %llu, is it ok?

Comment: The type of `0xffffffff + 1;` is the type of `0xffffffff` or of `int` if `int` is "larger". It does not help if you assign the result to a `unsigned long long` or an `unsigned int`. Any overflow that already happens during calculation will not vanish after assigning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892227/c-literal-integer-type

Comment: `unsigned long long resTestAgain = 0xfffffffff + 1;   // number of f is 8` No.... count again

Comment: `%llu` is OK for `unsigned long long`. But `%ld` is not OK for `sizeof`

Comment: What type is `0xffffffff` ? What type is `0xfffffffff` ? Once you answer that, you know what is going on

Comment: @Gerhardh My question is mainly about %llu for  0xffffffff + 1.

Comment: @Tom *But I use %llu, is it ok?* [No](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9):  "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @SupportUkraine `0xffffffff` and `0xfffffffff`  all are unsigned long long type.

Comment: @Tom *0xffffffff and 0xfffffffff all are unsigned long long type*  Why do you think those integer literals are `unsigned long long` types?

Comment: @Tom Nope.... That's your mistake. They are different types. Adding `1` to `0xffffffff` results in zero

Comment: If you wrote `float f = 0xffffffff;` would that make `0xffffffff` a `float`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The `float` example is good. Nice.

Comment: @SupportUkraine "Adding 1 to 0xffffffff results in zero" but 0xffffffff  is unsigned long long that occupy 64-bits.

Comment: @Tom Nope... With 8 f like `0xffffffff` you don't get 64 bits. 32 bits will do. Then adding 1 leads to .... tada, zero

Comment: @AndrewHenle "would that make 0xffffffff a float", print with %f will display float number.

Comment: @SupportUkraine "With 8 f like 0xffffffff you don't get 64 bits", but I define With 8 f like 0xffffffff as unsigned long long.

Comment: @Tom It doesn't matter at all what type you write on the Left-Hand-Side. The types used for the Right-Hand-Side is completely independent of  Left-Hand-Side. It's only when the assignment/initialization is done i.e. the `=` that the Left-Hand-Side type matters. And in your case that's too late... The Right-Hand-Side have already reached the result zero.

Comment: @tom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277799/type-selection-for-literal-numeric-values-in-c

Comment: @Tom *print with %f will display float number.*  You might as well have said, "My pony has 4 hooves".  That would be as applicable to your problem right now, because `printf()`'s `%f` format specifier literally has nothing to do with what type of value the integer literal `0xffffffff` is.  You need to think about **what `0xffffffff` IS**.  And **only** `0xffffffff`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Why With 9 f like 0xfffffffff + 1 is not overflow?

Comment: @Tom Print these: `sizeof(0xffffffff)`, `sizeof(0xfffffffff)`, `sizeof(0xffffffff + 1)`, `sizeof(0xfffffffff + 1)`

Comment: @VLL ok. I try it.

Comment: @VLL print 4 8 4 8, it look that I declare `unsigned long long` that is usefulless.

Comment: "My question is mainly about %llu for 0xffffffff + 1" You didn't get it. You do not pass `0xffffffff + 1` to `printf`. You pass a `unsigned long long`. For that `%llu` is OK. But `0xffffffff + 1` isn't an `unsigned long long` unless you add `ULL` suffix.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you for you replay. `0xffffffff + 1 isn't an unsigned long long unless you add ULL suffix or force convert (unsigned long long) 0xffffffff + 1` , that I learned at long before, then long time don't use relative it, so I forget it. At at begin my problem is that  I want to print (0xffffffff+1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 that output is 0, but (4294967295 + 1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 output 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Everything in C has a type, including these things: `1` which are known as *integer constants*.
- Normally an integer constant has type `int`. Or unless it is too large to fit in an `int`, it has type `long`, or otherwise if still not large enough, `long long`. In all these cases it is a signed type.
- Hex (and octal) integer constants are special. In case a hex integer constant can't fit in an `int`, it will become `unsigned int`, or if it can't fit in one either, then `long`, then `unsigned long` and so on.

So on a 32 bit `int` system, then `0xffffffff` will get type `unsigned int` and `1` will get type `int`. Neither which is a type large enough to store the result of `0xffffffff + 1` so we already found the bug here.

Now as it happens, if you have one operand of type `unsigned int` and one of signed `int`, an implicit conversion (*the usual arithmetic conversions*) converts the signed type to unsigned. Details here: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Therefore both operands end up `unsigned int` and the result of the addition will also be `unsigned int`. The result of `(unsigned int)0xffffffff + (unsigned int)1` is well-defined in C, on a 32 bit `int` system we will get a wrap-around and the result is `0`.

What types you use in the rest of the program from there doesn't really matter because the result is already calculated.

Conclusion: which type that any operation in C is carried out as, has *everything* to do with the operands of the given operator and *nothing* to do with some left operand of assignment where the result will be stored later.

For the same reason as if you write down 1+1=2 on a paper and then store that paper in a folder, the equation on the paper does not magically change depending on what type of folder you store it in - it has already been carried out.

Comment: In your answer "Hex (and octal) integer constants are special. In case a hex integer constant can't fit in an int, it will become unsigned int, or if it can't fit in one either, then long and so on." that I never heard. Thank you for you explain. As "So on a 32 bit int system", I am using 64-bits computer.

Comment: @Tom Yeah it should say "32 bit int system" which in the real world means any 32 or 64 bit CPU. 8 or 16 bit CPUs use 16 bit int.

Comment: @Lundin  I ever don't heard "8 or 16 bit CPUs use 16 bit int.". Thank you for your explain.

Comment: Does result of `(unsigned int)0xffffffff + (unsigned int)1` and `4294967295 + 1`  different?

Comment: @Tom Yes, `4294967295` will result in a `long` or `long long` and the result will become `4294967296`. However, in case you write `2147483647 + 1` then both operands are `int` and you get an integer overflow bug, which is undefined behavior unlike unsigned wrap-around.

Comment: Since I was curious (and since the accepted answer forgot to make the distinction between hex vs. decimal literals), I made a demo (https://godbolt.org/z/7sab5csrK) that shows how `4294967295` has a signed 64-bit type but `0xffffffff` has an unsigned 32-bit type, when compiled for x86-64.  (I used C++ for its `auto` keyword to infer a variable's type from the right-hand side.  C uses the same rules.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's kind of a FAQ, I remember this curious question where someone had managed to write a rather surprising bug because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34182672/584518.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [@rici’s answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892445/707111) (about C++, but [the same rule applies to C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant)), unsigned types are candidates for hex integer literals. `0xffffffff` fits in a 32-bit `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, so one of those is its type. Then the `int` `1` is converted to `unsigned long/int` for the addition, which overflows. Finally, the `unsigned long/int` `0` is converted to `unsigned long long` to become the initial value for `resTestBad`.

Use `0xffffffffULL` to force the literal to be `unsigned long long` from the get go.

(When you add another `f`, the value no longer fits in an `unsigned long`, so the literal already has type `long long` and it works.)

Comment: I declaration unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;  that means occupy 64-bits, why 0xffffffff save into 32-bit?

Comment: @Tom *why 0xffffffff save into 32-bit?*  Why do you think `0xffffffff` is a 64-bit value?  Going back to `float`:  if you **assign** `0xffffffff` to a `float`, does that make `0xffffffff` itself a `float`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Because I declare 0xffffffff as unsigned long long. See unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;  // number of f is 8

Answer (score 3):

*This answer assumes `int` to be 32 bits (which is the most common size)*

> Is it a Bug of CPU or bug of VMWare Workstation?

No, it **not** a bug. It's how the C standard says it has to be done.

When doing

```
unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;
```

the first step is to calculate

```
0xffffffff + 1;
```

To do that the compiler needs to ensure the the operands at both side of `+` has the same type. So first it needs to figure out the types.

```
0xffffffff
```

is in decimal the value 4294967295 which can't be stored in a 32 bit **signed** value. However, it **can** be stored in a 32 bit **unsigned** value, and was written in hex in the source.  (As [@Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77015141/unsigned-long-long-restestbad-0xffffffff-1-print-0-with-llu-but-unsigned/77015666#77015666) points out, `4294967295` in the source will only pick signed types, unlike hex literals not considering `unsigned int` as a possibility.  So it will be a 64-bit signed type, either `long` or `long long` depending on whether `long` is 64 of 32-bit.  You can check this yourself by printing `sizeof(4294967295)` vs. `sizeof(0xffffffff)`.

`1` has type `int`, which can be implicitly converted to `unsigned int`, so the compiler selects 32-bit unsigned for the calculation.

So the calculation is done as:

```
(unsigned int)0xffffffff + (unsigned int)1;
```

This gives (a well defined) overflow to the final result zero.

So

```
unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;
```

is really the same as

```
unsigned long long resTestBad = (unsigned int)0;
```

And notice, the type on the **Left Hand Side** of the `=` has absolutely no impact on the calculation of the Right Hand Side. No matter if you write `unsigned long long resTestBad` or `float resTestBad` or `double resTestBad`, the calculation on the Right Hand Side is the same. It will always be:

```
SomeType resTestBad = (unsigned int)0;
```

BTW: Try this:

```
float f = 5/2;
```

Will you get `2.5` because you have `float` on the Left Hand Side? No, the division is still an integer division so the result is `(int)2`.

When you use 9 `f` instead of 8 `f`, the value can no longer be saved in a 32 bit type so the compiler selects a 64 bit type for the calculation. Consequently, there won't be an overflow.

> How can I solve it?

By forcing the Right Hand Side calculation to be done in 64 bit. For instance:

```
0xffffffffULL + 1
```

Comment: I see book name "The c programming language", you said "C standard", does it in that book?

Comment: The C standard is the document that describes how C works. It has all the rules that C compilers must follow.

Comment: @Tom Drafts of the standard can be found for free: https://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html Read 6.4.4.1 and 6.3.1.8

Comment: According to you answer, I find other solution: unsigned long long resTestBad = (unsigned long long)0xffffffff + 1;  Thank you very much for you answer and link that you provided.

Comment: @Tom yep, you can use a cast like ` (unsigned long long)0xffffffff`. It will work.... but it's more common to use suffixs.

Comment: Why `unsigned long long resA = 4294967295 + 1;` output `resA is 4294967296`?4294967295 is 0xffffffff, as you said "(unsigned int)0xffffffff + (unsigned int)1;, This gives (a well defined) overflow to the final result zero.". I think it should be output 0.

Comment: Does result of (unsigned int)0xffffffff + (unsigned int)1 and 4294967295 + 1 different?

Comment: @Tom: As Lundin's answer explains, the way you write the number in the source determines whether `unsigned int` is a candidate before moving on to a larger signed type like `long`.  Yes for hex like `0xffffffff`, but no for `4294967295`.   https://godbolt.org/z/7sab5csrK) that shows how `4294967295` has a signed 64-bit type but `0xffffffff` has an unsigned 32-bit type, when compiled for x86-64.  (I used C++ for its `auto` keyword to infer a variable's type from the right-hand side.  C uses the same rules.)  You should accept Lundin's answer which explains that it's not just the numeric value.

Comment: Or @SupportUkraine should fix this answer to avoid implying that `0xffffffff` and `4294967295` are the same thing as integer literal constants in C; they have different types.  `sizeof(4294967295)` is 8, `sizeof(0xffffffff)` is 4, on mainstream implementations where `int` is 32-bit and the next larger integer size is 64-bit.  Or I could edit...

Comment: @PeterCordes Before my question is not say clear, please see my updated answer.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Can you explain that value size of 0xffffffff and 4294967295 is the same, why 0xffffffff as unsigned int type(occupy 32-bit), however 4294967295 may be as long or long long or other type(occupy 64-bit)? I updated my answer. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Tom: That's just how C was designed, that base 10 constants in the source can only be signed types, but hex constants can also be unsigned if they fit.  See Lundin's answer.  As for the language-design reasons why, it's typical to use unsigned types when doing bit-manipulation stuff, and it's also typical to write constants in hex when you care about their bit-patterns more than their numeric value, so this rule is sometimes helpful.  Early C might have gotten that rule before introduction of suffixes like `1U` vs. `1ULL` that let you specify the type and signedness of a literal constant.

Comment: @Tom: If C were being redesigned from scratch these days, I think most people would be in favour of a different design, because the current behaviour leads to non-intuitive results like you ran into where different ways of writing the same number have different behaviour.  I'm not sure what Rust does; it generally requires you to be explicit about types, like if you had a u8 and an i16, you'd have to explicitly convert them if you wanted to add them.  But IDK about literal constants.

Comment: @Tom: See [Why are decimal and hexadecimal integer literals treated differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36560143) about the design decision.  It's a C++ question, but since C++11 changed to match C99, the answer quotes the C99 committee's stated rationale, which is what I guessed, that hex constants are more often bit-patterns or masks, so shouldn't be widened just to avoid having the high bit set, thus they can choose from unsigned types as well.  Also related: [What are integer literal types? And how are they stored?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41405578) re: `-` being a separate unary op.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your explain. That is to say, when using a number, it is best to specify its type, such as `(unsigned long long) 0xffffffff + 1` or `0xffffffffULL + 1` or `4294967295ULL + 1` or `(unsigned long long) 0xffffffff` or `0xffffffffULL` or `4294967295ULL`

Answer (score 2):

For starters it is much better to use the conversion specifier `%zu` to output values of the type `size_t` instead of `%ld` as you are doing:

```
 printf("resTestOk is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %ld\n", resTestOk, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

Firstly though the type `size_t` in general represents an alias for the type `unsigned long` however according to the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>)

> 4 The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.

It seems in your system `size_t` is indeed an alias for the type `unsigned long` and outputted values can be represented in objects of the signed type `long int`.

Now let's consider for example this declaration:

```
unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;
```

The unsigned hexadecimal constant `0xffffffff` can be represented in an object of the type `unsigned int`. So it has the type `unsigned int`. Thus in this expression:

```
0xffffffff + 1
```

there is used the arithmetic for objects of the type `unsigned int` (the integer constant `1` is also converted  to the type `unsigned int` due to usual arithmetic conversions).

As a result there is an overflow because the result can not be represented in an object of the type `unsigned int`. And the value of the expression is `0`.

The same situation takes place in this code snippet:

```
unsigned long long resH = (0xffffffff+1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
printf("%llu\n", resH);
```

where the expression `0xffffffff+1` of the type `unsigned int` produces an overflow for objects of that type and yields `0`.

As for this declaration:

```
unsigned long long resTestAgain = 0xfffffffff + 1;
```

then the hexadecimal constant `0xfffffffff` can not be represented in an object of the type unsigned int (provided that `sizeof( unsigned int )` is not greater than `4`). If `sizeof( long int )` is equal to `8`  or if it is equal to `4` but `sizeof( long long int )` equal to `8` (and in your program it indeed is equal to `8`) then the constant can be represented in an object of the type either `long int`. or `long long int`.

So in this expression:

```
0xfffffffff + 1
```

there is used the arithmetic for objects of the type `long int` or `long long int`. And the result of the expression can be also represented in an object of that type.

As for this code snippet:

```
unsigned long long resA = 4294967295 + 1; 
printf("resA is %llu, sizeof(unsigned long long) is %ld\n", resA, sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

then the constant `4294967295` is greater than the value of `INT_MAX` equal to `2147483647`. So it has type `long int` if  `sizeof( long int )` is greater than `sizeof( int )` or `long long int` otherwise. And the result of the expression `4294967295 + 1` can be represented n object of that type as a positive value.

Pay attention to the following quote from the C Standard (6.4.4.1 Integer constants) relative to types of integer constants

> 5 The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
> list in which its value can be represented.

```
                            Octal or Hexadecimal
Suffix     Decimal Constant            Constant
===============================================================
none             int                     int
                 long int                unsigned int
                 long long int           long int
                                         unsigned long int
                                         long long int
                                         unsigned long long int
================================================================
u or U           unsigned int            unsigned int
                 unsigned long int       unsigned long int
                 unsigned long long int  unsigned long long int
================================================================  
l or L           long int                long int
                 long long int           unsigned long int
                                         long long int
                                         unsigned long long int
================================================================
ll or LL         long long int           long long int
                                         unsigned long long int
================================================================  
Both u or U      unsigned long long int  unsigned long long int
and ll or LL
=================================================================
```

Comment: I declaration unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;  that means occupy 64-bits, why 0xffffffff save into 32-bit?

Comment: @Tom Because the C standard says so. Read "6.4.4.1 Integer constants" of the standard. As I already told you: Whatever type you have on LHS means nothing to types on RHS. This is also why `float f = 5/2;` will **not** give you `2.5`

Comment: @SupportUkraine I see book named "The c programming language".

Comment: @SupportUkraine Why With 9 f like 0xfffffffff + 1 is not overflow?

Comment: @Tom Becaus 9 `f` can't be stored in 32 bit. So the compiler selects 64 bits instead. Consequently no overflow.

Comment: @SupportUkraine But I declare unsigned long long resTestBad = 0xffffffff + 1;  // number of f is 8. Please unsigned long long.

Comment: @Tom I told you several time. It does **not** matter which type you write on the left side of the `=` See my answer.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I know, but it is different for my think.

Comment: @Tom  In this expression 0xffffffff + 1 there is used the arithmetic for objects of the type unsigned int. And only the result is assigned to an object of the type unsigned long long int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  I find other solution: unsigned long long resTestBad = (unsigned long long)0xffffffff + 1;

Comment: *type size_t in general represents an alias for the type unsigned long* - Maybe you mean "typically" or "often"?  It's definitely not true *in general*, since there are mainstream counterexamples. Windows x64 is an LLP64 ABI so `unsigned long` is a 32-bit type, but it allows array sizes larger than 4GiB so `size_t` has to be `unsigned long long`, matching `uintptr_t`.  Most non-Windows 64-bit systems use LP64 ABI, often derived from System V, so outside of Windows yeah `size_t` often `unsigned long`.  Presumably some 16-bit systems have 16-bit `size_t` = `unsigned int`.

Comment: @PeterCordes In my answer there is written clear. And moreover there is provided a quote from the C Standard. What is unclear?

Comment: "Generally" can mean that something is true everywhere, or almost everywhere.  That quote from the standard isn't just some obscure detail that doesn't come up on "normal" systems, it applies on a widely used platform, Windows x64.  Like I said, "typically" or "often" would be better choices for that sentence, to avoid the implication that `size_t = unsigned long` is a good assumption.  The OP is only printing small `size_t` values with `%ld`, so we can't tell whether it was looking at the low 32 bits of a register or the whole thing.  I'd expect the same output in Windows x64 for example.

Comment: From the OP's screen-capture animation, we can see they're doing this inside an Ubuntu VM, so `size_t` will match `%ld`, whether that's 32 or 64-bit.  But IDK if that was your basis for saying "it seems".

Comment: Oh right, so `%ld` definitely doesn't actually match. It just happens to work for non-huge numbers where the same bits can be interpreted as signed positive.  Anyway, regardless of what the rest of your answer says, I'm suggesting changing the word "generally", because that's something that's *not* generally true.  Correcting a potentially-misleading statement later is not as good as avoiding giving some readers the wrong impression in the first place. Not everyone reads every word of every answer. I'm not saying your answer is *technically* wrong, I'm suggesting what I think is an improvement